# Laravel parsing json output correctly

Tags: json

i am using this code in laravel .

```
 $user_detail = \App\Userpacakage::with('user.pacakage')->where('pacakage_id', '=', 1)->get(); //->lists('nombre', 'id')
        return response()->json($user_detail);
```

this is my json output ->

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"pacakage_id":1,"transaction_id":"jfjkgjgjkhkjkg55rtf","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","user":{"id":1,"name":"omsun","email":"omsun123@gmail.com","contact":2147483647,"regkey":"","created_at":"2015-11-21 01:18:33","updated_at":"2015-11-21 01:18:33","pacakage":[{"id":1,"title":"dsagdjas","description":"<p>\r\n\tsamndbmasndmas,<\/p>\r\n","tab_id":0,"from":"11\/27\/2015","to":"12\/03\/2015","days":22,"unlimited":0,"criteria":1,"category_id":1,"subcategory_id":0,"subject_id":0,"price":2432,"created_at":"2015-11-21 19:07:10","updated_at":"2015-11-21 19:07:10","pivot":{"user_id":1,"pacakage_id":1}}]}}]
```

using jquery i am using this code to fetch user details

```
$.get('api/classallocation?pacakage_id=' + pacakage_id, function (data) {

                    console.log(data);
                     $.each(data, function (i, user) {

                         console.log(user.name));
                     });
```

i want to know how to fetch the pacakage details in jquery ..like pacakage title ,price.

Comment: what exactly is your question? please add more information on what input you give and the output you get, and what your code looks like.

Comment: i am  laravel 
          $user_detail = \App\Userpacakage::with('user.pacakage')->where('pacakage_id', '=', 1)->get(); //->lists('nombre', 'id');
return response()->json($user_detail);

Comment: And what is the error or problem you have with the parsing? Please update your question.

Comment: now i have updated the question .pls help

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('api/classallocation?pacakage_id=' + pacakage_id, function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $.each(data, function (i, user) {
   console.log(user.pacakage[0].title));
});
```